# React / Meteor test using enzyme, props not loading

Tags: meteor, reactjs, enzyme

I have a test that is simply trying to test what is on the page when the react component renders, it looks like this

**Prospects.tests.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { chai } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai'
import { Random } from 'meteor/random';

import { Residents } from '/imports/collections/residents.jsx';
import Prospects from "/imports/client/ui/prospects/Prospects";

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  describe('Prospects', function() {
    it('renders with no prospects', function() {

      const item = shallow(<Prospects />);
      const node = item.find('table')
      chai.assert(node.hasClass('no-prospects'))
    });
  });
}
```

The problem is that at this point, my collection is still loading, so all enzyme sees when I console log the html:

`console.log(item.html())`

is

[image: html]

My component that renders this is:

**Prospects.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { FlowRouter as Router } from 'meteor/kadira:flow-router'
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data'
import { Residents } from '/imports/collections/residents.jsx'
import Griddle from 'griddle-react'

class Prospects extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(props){
    this.setState({prospects: props.prospects})
  }

  render() {
    if(!this.props.ready){
      return(
        <span>Loading...</span>
      )
    }

    return(
      <div><Griddle results={this.state.prospectsshowFilter={true}/</div>
    )
  }
}

export default createContainer(() => {
  const residents = Meteor.subscribe('residents')
  const ready = residents.ready()
  return {
    prospects: ready ? Residents.find({}).fetch(): [],
    ready: ready,
  }
}, Prospects)
```

So my two questions are:

1) Is there a better way to ensure props are loaded so I don't have to show 'Loading...'

2) In enzyme is there a way I can have it re-render once the props are loaded? I've tried to use item.update() but it doesn't work because the props are not getting set.

Comment: what version of meteor are you running?

Comment: Meteor 1.3.4.1 is the version

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?